# zClip not copying value on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, zclip

Here is my code.

```
$('a.copy').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.zclip({
        path : 'path/to/ZeroClipboard.swf',
        copy : function(){
            var copyText = $this.prev().val();
            console.debug(copyText);
            return copyText;
       }
    });
 });
```

After clicking the button, '`copyText`' is printed out correctly (via `console.debug`), but the value seems not to be returned.

The problem is seems to be "[iButton](http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm)" plugin, when i comment that plugin, the zclip is worked, but I don't know why. Anyone experienced this issue?

P.S. Firefox works fine

Answer (score 1):

This has had me stumped for a couple hours, I have a project using both iButton and ZeroClipboard and have the same issues.

The problem is with iButton attaching a mouseup event to $('document') that interferes with other mouseup events. I don't have time to hunt down a complete fix for the iButton component but searching for the following line in jquery.ibutton.js  Rev:  1.0.03

```
$('document').bind("mouseup.iButton_" + id + " touchend.iButton_" + id, function(e) {
```

and replace it with

```
$container.bind("mouseup.iButton_" + id + " touchend.iButton_" + id, function(e) {
```

cleared the problem up for me, but there is probably a better fix.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){    
 $('a.copy').each(function(){
   $this.zclip({
    path : 'path/to/ZeroClipboard.swf',
    copy : function(){
    var copyText=$(this).prev().val();
    console.debug(copyText);
    return copyText ;   
   }
    });
   });
 });
```

first make sure that you include the jquery library and zclip js file

Comment: I think the problem is [iButton plugin](http://www.givainc.com/labs/ibutton_jquery_plugin.htm), because after comment this plugin, it works fine.

Comment: it may be the two javascript library are doing some conflict

Comment: I don't know js that much, so I can't find anything weird in the "iButton" script.

Comment: it may be cause by a conflict between the two javascript libraries the one of iButton and the zclip add jquery.noconflict in your code or use another js library that wont do a conflict

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but I still can't get it to work. I think the only way to do is to modify the "iButton" library.